Importing data, addons and setup from Blender 4.2.3 (or previous) to Blender 4.3
Anytime I updated Blender to a new release the program, at the beginning, showed me a panel asking me if i wanted to import data addons and so on from my previous release. Updating to Blender 4.3 I didn't find this very useful option. Someone can say me how to do that?
Thank you in advance

It was on the initial splash screen as usual here and all addons and settings transferred fine. Not sure how you can initiate it again though.

I do not know where to find it on Mac or Linux, but on Windows the user preferences are stored under
%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.3\config
There is a blend file called userpref.blend, if you delete it the splash screen will show the button to import previous version settings next time you open Blender.
There is also the startup.blend but I guess you don't have to delete it, it should be overwritten once you import the old settings.
As I said, I do not know the path on other systems, but I am sure you can google it somehow.
